# Using a greedy feature selection algorithm for linear regression in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression, feature-selection

*This is a homework problem for a machine learning course I'm taking. I'll be as descriptive as I can regarding the approaches I took, what worked, and what didn't.*

We are given four types of data sets: `dev_sample.npy`, `dev_label.npy`, `test_sample.npy`, and `test_label.npy`. We first load the data set as follows:

```python
import numpy as np
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X_dev = np.load("./dev_sample.npy") # shape (900, 126)
y_dev = np.load("./dev_label.npy") # shape (900,)
X_test = np.load("/test_sample.npy") # shape (100, 126)
y_test = np.load("./test_label.npy") # shape (100,)
```

The problem we need to solve is to implement a "greedy feature selection" algorithm until the best 100 of the 126 features are selected. Basically we train models with one feature, select the best one and store it, train 125 models with each remaining feature paired with the selected, choose the next best one and store it, and continue until we have reached 100.

Here is the code:

```python
# Define linear regression function
# You may use sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression
# Your code here
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
# End your code

# Basic settings. DO NOT MODIFY
selected_feature = []
sel_num = 100
valid_split = 1/5
cv = ShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=valid_split, random_state=0)

selected_train_error = []
selected_valid_error = []

# For greedy selection
for sel in range(sel_num) :
    min_train_error = +1000
    min_valid_error = +1000
    min_feature = 0

    for i in range(X_dev.shape[1]) :
        train_error_ith = []
        valid_error_ith = []

        # Select feature greedy
        # Hint : There should be no duplicated feature in selected_feature

        # Your code here
        X_dev_fs = X_dev[:, i]
        if (i in selected_feature):
            continue
        else:
            pass
        # End your code


        # For cross validation
        for train_index, test_index in cv.split(X_dev) : # train_index.shape = 720, test_index.shape = 180, 5 iterations
            X_train, X_valid = X_dev_fs[train_index], X_dev_fs[test_index]
            y_train, y_valid = y_dev[train_index], y_dev[test_index]

            # Derive training error, validation error
            # You may use sklearn.metrics.mean_squared_error, model.fit(), model.predict()

            # Your code here
            model_train = lin_reg.fit(X_train.reshape(-1, 1), y_train.reshape(-1, 1))
            predictions_train = model_train.predict(X_valid.reshape(-1, 1))
            train_error_ith.append(mean_squared_error(y_valid, predictions_train))

            model_valid = lin_reg.fit(X_valid.reshape(-1, 1), y_valid.reshape(-1, 1))
            predictions_valid = model_valid.predict(X_valid.reshape(-1, 1))
            valid_error_ith.append(mean_squared_error(y_valid, predictions_valid))

            # End your code

    # Select best performance feature set on each features
    # You should choose the feature which has minimum mean cross validation error

    # Your code here

    min_train_error = train_error_ith[np.argmin(train_error_ith)]
    min_valid_error = valid_error_ith[np.argmin(valid_error_ith)]
    min_feature = np.argmin(valid_error_ith)

    # End your code

print('='*50)
print("# of selected feature(s) : {}".format(sel+1))
print("min_train_error: {}".format(min_train_error))
print("min_valid_error: {}".format(min_valid_error))
print("Selected feature of this iteration : {}".format(min_feature))
selected_feature.append(min_feature)
selected_train_error.append(min_train_error)
selected_valid_error.append(min_valid_error)
```

The algorithm that I had in mind when filling in the `#Your code` sections is that `X_dev_fs` would hold the feature of the current iteration along with the previously selected features. We would then use cross validation to derive training and CV errors.

The current output that I get after running this program is

```
==================================================
# of selected feature(s) : 1
min_train_error: 9.756743239446392
min_valid_error: 9.689856536723353
Selected feature of this iteration : 1
==================================================
# of selected feature(s) : 2
min_train_error: 9.70991346883164
min_valid_error: 9.674875050182653
Selected feature of this iteration : 1
==================================================
```

and so on, with the `# of selected feature(s)` going on until 100.

The problem is that `Selected feature of this iteration :` should not output the same number more than once. I'm also having trouble figuring out how to store the best feature and use it with the subsequent iterations.

The **questions** that I have are:

1. Why is my `selected_feature` list containing the same duplicate features, and how do I prevent that?
2. How do I store the best feature in `selected_feature`, then use that paired up with each subsequent remaining feature?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

Here are the links to the files that I am loading into the variables, in case anybody needs them.

[`dev_sample.npy`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lzTjdpEAAz8gHjIiI6mm5Raum2UmbrCu/view)

[`dev_label.npy`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1clUEiksZoT5j36bCjPSIlix9Gsb2fL5Y/view)

[`test_sample.npy`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kAoFD32wu_E5v7tNdbstXkYQxk-AwqEd/view)

[`test_label.npy`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qa3RMg0tubPx0YfSE5dGECnLU6voq_5s/view)

Comment: I do not have the files you are loading, would you please post a link to them?

Comment: Hello. I'm sorry but unfortunately I don't have a link to the files. We were told to download the files from a private server the school uses. The most information that I know about them is that the `X_dev` has 900 samples with a total of 126 features, and `X_test` is the same except with 100 samples. The `y` files are the labels for the samples.

Comment: Would you please put the files somewhere publicly available, such as Dropbox or google docs, and then post a link to that location?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I edited the links into the original question. Thanks for the tip.